# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid callback:

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml, cron

I'm trying to write a cron. I'm using magento 1.9.

This is my config.xml file:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Kode_Testmodule>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Kode_Testmodule>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <Kode_Testmodule_SomeFreeRouterName1>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Kode_Testmodule</module>
                <frontName>test-module</frontName>
            </args>
        </Kode_Testmodule_SomeFreeRouterName1>
    </routers>
</frontend>

<global>
    <models>
        <kodetestmodule>
            <class>Kode_Testmodule_Model</class>
        </kodetestmodule>                         
    </models>
</global>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <kode_testmodule>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/2 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run><model>testmodule/cronmodule::orderstoday</model></run>
        </kode_testmodule>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

This is my Cronmodule.php:

```
<?php
class Kode_Testmodule_Model_Cronmodule{
public function orderstoday() {
    die("hello out");
}
}

?>
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid callback: testmodule/cronmodule::orderstoday does not exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cron\Model\Observer.php(301): Mage::throwException('Invalid callbac...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cron\Model\Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\cron.php(74): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#6 {main}
```

Any help whatsoever will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below config.xml :

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Kode_Testmodule>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Kode_Testmodule>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <testmodule>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Kode_Testmodule</module>
                <frontName>testmodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </testmodule>
    </routers>
</frontend>

<global>
    <models>
        <testmodule>
            <class>Kode_Testmodule_Model</class>
        </testmodule>                         
    </models>
</global>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <testmodule>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/2 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run><model>testmodule/cronmodule::orderstoday</model></run>
        </testmodule>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

and let me know if it works.

Comment: Enjoy..Glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your config file:

```
<crontab>
        <jobs>
            <kode_testmodule>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>                    
                <run><model>testmodule/observer::orderstoday</model></run>
            </kode_testmodule>
        </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Creat Observer.php and place this code:

```
<?php
class Kode_Testmodule_Model_Observer
{
     public function orderstoday() {
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
    ->setToName('Admin')
    ->setToEmail('admin@gmail.com')
    ->setBody('Hello')
    ->setSubject('Test Alert')
    ->setFromEmail('admin@gmail.com')
    ->setFromName('Magento Store')
    ->setType('html');
    $mail->send();
     }
 }
```

and rather to place die, send mail to your account so it would be easy to see function is working or not.